# Score based on time

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm totally new to Swift (started working on this yesterday) so I don't know where to start.

Basically I'm making a game where the score shall increment every 0.25 seconds (after the game started - `touchesBegan`). I was thinking in something with `waitForDuration(0.25)`, but I didn't know what to do.

And I also have to place it in the top center of screen (landscape). I tried using `.position` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it!! I mean, I found some code, videos and texts that helped to do it =)

```
//Score
scoreLabel.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height / 2)
self.addChild(scoreLabel)

//Score incrementing by time
let delay = SKAction.waitForDuration(0.25)
let incrementScore = SKAction.runBlock ({
    self.score = self.score + 1
    self.scoreLabel.text = "\(self.score)"
})
self.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([delay,incrementScore])))
```

I didn't used NSTimer because I read that it couldn't be paused/resumed (what I will need to do later).

Thank you =)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome To SO. Your question is really vague and really broad. Not a good fit for this site.

Since you're new I'll give you a hint to get you started. Go do some reading and try to make it work on your own before asking for more help.

Create a repeating NSTimer using 
 [`scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSTimer/scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:)

Make the method that timer calls increment a score instance variable and update a label

Comment: Don't use NSTimer in Sprite-Kit - the scene won't know about the timer and it can mess things up (e.q. If you pause the SKScene, the timer won't pause too). Use SKActions or do things in Update() by analysing the time passed since Update() was last called.

Comment: Fair enough. I haven't used SpriteKit.